# Data validation backward compatibility bug

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, office365

I have been given a spreadsheet made in Office 365 that uses data validation on several cells. The validation uses a range of cells from another sheet in the spreadsheet.

When opening the document in Office 2007, the validation has disappeared. When manually recreating the data validation in 2007 and saving the sheet, it can now be opened.

When on a cell, I click the 'DataValidation...' button, it brings up a dialog that allows selecting a list of valid values from which you can select a cell range to use. The cell develops a dropdown arrow from which to select the valid values. In 2007 it is not possible to select another sheet from the dialog, but it is possible to type, say `=Sheet2!A1:A5`, to get the validation range. The workbook made in Office 365 with this feature (from another sheet) is ignored by 2007.

What is going on?

Comment: Follow the instructions here and see if you can see anything about why it's not working: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/check-file-compatibility-with-earlier-versions-d9856881-5875-4c58-915f-06859b2943a7

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have 365 to test it with, I'd have to get the sender to test it.

Comment: What functions, exactly, are you using?

Comment: @Ramhound when on a cell, I click the 'DataValidation...' button. It brings up a dialog that allows selecting a list of valid values, from which you can select a cell range to use. The cell develops a drop down arrow from which to select the valid values. In 2007 it is not possible to select another sheet, but it is possible to type say `=Sheet2!A1:A5` to get the validation range. The workbook made in O365 with this feature (from another sheet) is ignored by 2007.

Comment: @RajeshS unfortunately as always, IP protection wouldn't allow that, and I can't create a new one to show the point.

Comment: @SamForbis indeed that issue is listed as an incompatibility. I find it colossally hard to understand how 2007 and 365 are both able to perform, function, save and load the function to the exact same file format, but that 365 writes it in a way incompatible with 2007.